# Prop callback not returning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a [Material UI Table](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table) with ReactJS and would like to change a state variable whenever a row is selected/deselected.  `Table` has `onRowSelection` which is triggered each time a row is selected:

```
<Table
  height='300px'
  fixedHeader={true}
  multiSelectable={true}
  showRowHover={true}
  onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection.bind(this)}
>
```

I have the following function passed to the `onRowSelection` prop:

```
handleRowSelection(selectedRows) {
  let contactsImport = [];

  if (selectedRows === 'all') {
    contactsImport = this.state.contacts.new;
  } else if (selectedRows !== 'none') {
    selectedRows.forEach((index) => {
      contactsImport.push(this.state.contacts.new[index]);
    });
  }

  this.setState({
    contactsImport:contactsImport
  });
}
```

This sets the state correctly, however it prevents the Table Row selection from functioning correctly. If I click a row, the checkbox doesn't check -- it seems like it is checking and then instantly unchecking itself because I get the 'ripple' animation but no checkmark.

**Removing the call to `setState` fixes the issue, so is it possible `setState` is preventing the callback from returning correctly?** Or might this be a bug with Material UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to manage the `selected` property of a single row component from the state if you wish to control it programmatically. `selected` property is `false` by default, so when rerendering happens by `setState` it'll be reset back to `false`